# How to find the limit of $a_n = (3^n - 2^n)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Im trying to find the limit of the following sequence: $a_n =3^n-2^n$.

I tried proving with induction that $a_n<2^n$, and then demand that $2^n>E$ for every $E>0$, but it just went wrong.

thank you!!

Comment: Did you mean to say $a_n \gt 2^n$ for $n \ge 2$?

Comment: Hard to give a satisfactory answer for you without knowing what book you are reading. Could you please cite the name of the book? Where is this exercise from?

Answer (score 7):

**HINT**

Note that

$$3^n-2^n = 3^n\left(1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\right)$$

If you want to proceed by induction, it suffices to prove that

$$a_n =3^n-2^n \ge n$$

Answer (score 3):

$$3^n-2^n=(3-2)(3^{n-1}+3^{n-1}2+3^{n-2}2^2+\cdots 2^{n-1})$$ and *all* these terms are growing to infinity !

---

**Alternatively:**

$$3^n-2^n=3\cdot3^{n-1}-2\cdot2^{n-1}>3\cdot3^{n-1}-2\cdot3^{n-1}=3^{n-1}.$$

E.g.

$$81-16>27.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$a_n =3^n-2^n=(2+1)^n-2^n={n\choose 1}2^{n-1}+{n\choose 2}2^{n-2}+\cdots +1 \to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find $$\lim\limits_{\to\infty} a_n $$
Notice that :$a_n=3^n-2^n=((\frac{3}{2})^n-1)$
Because $\frac{3}{2}>1\Longrightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  \frac {3}{2}^n=\infty $

But, we'll prove with help of induction 
Proposition:
$a_n\geq n$, for all $n\in\mathbb {N} $

1. For $n=1$, it's clear that $3^1-2^1=1\geq 1$
2. Assume it's true for $1\leq k\leq n $, that $3^k-2^k>k$
3. For $n=k+1$, $3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}=3^k.3-2^k.2=3^k-2^k+2.3^k-2.k\geq k+1$, hence $3^n-2^n\geq n $, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

What we're gonna do?

Take any $M>0$, we'll prove that exist n such that $a_n>M $,but how to do it?
Well, because  $M>0$, by Archmedean Property, there exists  $n\in\mathbb {N}$ such that $M<n $, and from our proposition we know that :$$a_n\geq M $$, hence for all $n_1\geq n\Longrightarrow a_{n_1}>M$

Meaning that $a_n$ is not bounded from above hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty $